# Calling connection.rollback() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

Running the project throws this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.myproject.crud.EmployeesJDBCImpl.withDB(EmployeesJDBCImpl.java:157)
    com.myproject.crud.EmployeesJDBCImpl.doList(EmployeesJDBCImpl.java:119)
    com.myproject.crud.EmployeesJDBCImpl.listEmployees(EmployeesJDBCImpl.java:111)
    com.myproject.crud.EmployeesJDBCImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.listEmployees(EmployeesJDBCImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    com.myproject.crud.EmployeesListServlet.doGet(EmployeesListServlet.java:36)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

The `try` block fails and it jumps to the `catch` block where it seems like the `connection` object is empty when `connection.rollback()` gets called. Having a hard time understanding why that happens. Username and password provided in `context.xml` are correct.

**EmployeesJDBCImpl.java**

```
package com.myproject.crud;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@ApplicationScoped @JDBC
public class EmployeesJDBCImpl implements EmployeesRepository {

    @Resource(name="jdbc/EmployeesDB")
    private DataSource dS;

    @Override
    public Employee viewEmployee(final String id) {
        return withDB(new JDBCRunner<Employee>(){
            @Override
            public Employee run(Connection connection) throws Exception{
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id = ?");

                preparedStatement.setString(1, id);

                ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()){
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.setId(rs.getString("id"));
                    employee.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                    employee.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
                    employee.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));                   
                    return employee;
                }else{
                    return null;
                }
        }});
    }

    private <T> T withDB(JDBCRunner<T> runner){
        Connection connection = null;

        try{
            connection = dS.getConnection();
            boolean auto = connection.getAutoCommit();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            T result = runner.run(connection);
            connection.commit();
            connection.setAutoCommit(auto);
            return result;
        }catch(Exception e){
            try{
                connection.rollback(); // Nullpointer exception here
            }catch(SQLException ex){
            }
            //throw new EmployeesException(e);
        }finally{
            if(connection != null){
                try{
                    connection.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**META-INF/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/EmployeesDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="root" password="secret" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
</Context>
```

**WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
...
    <description>MySQL Employees App</description>
    <resource-ref>
      <description>db connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/EmployeesDB</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your connection was not properly created. You should check if the `connection` is not null before performing a rollback.

Also, you should log, at least, the error, that way you will be able to figure what is going on.

I suspect that your `dS` object is null, probably it was not injected properly because of a name mismatch.

Comment: I agree, but why would it not be created properly in the first place is what confuses me.

Comment: @user1701467 See my updated answer, you should log the error, that will point you to the issue.

Comment: connection = dS.getConnection(); Where have you initialized the datasource?

Comment: @AbhishekGirish
At the top: `private DataSource dS;` then `connection = dS.getConnection();`

Comment: @user1701467 You should considering using log4j or another log framework, but `e.printStackTrace();` before your rollback statement will help you figure out the issue pretty quickly.

Comment: @dan
So, I did and it gave me this: `Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown database 'javatest')` which seems to be the `context.xml` problem, but after I changed url to appropriate database it still gives the same error with `javatest`.

Comment: @user1701467 Probably it's not picking your url changes properly. Ensure that you are modifying the used context.xml file

Comment: Hmm, it seems like the `context.xml` in Servers was conflicting with `context.xml` inside my project. After removing the Resource xml code from Tomcat's `context.xml` seemed to fix it. Didn't know that...

Comment: @user1701467 I was suspecting something like that :).

Answer (score 1):

Try to log the exception from the try block.

Most probably, this line will throw the exception:
 connection = dS.getConnection();

In general, you should avoid to catch all exceptions if possible. And log exceptions so you know whats happening. Because exceptions are, like the name suggests, not wanted.

--tb

Comment: Actually it gives `Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown database 'javatest')` then the rollback one. I changed the `javatest` to appropriate database name in the `context.xml`, but it keeps giving the same error with the same `javatest`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see where you have initialized your DataSource

```
 connection = dS.getConnection();
```

You must have some lookup code for dS

Something similar to:

```
Context ctx=new InitialContext();                        
DataSource dS=(DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/sampledb");   
Connection con=dS.getConnection();
```

Comment: Yes, but isn't that what `@Resource(name="jdbc/EmployeesDB")` is for?

Comment: may be there is some mismatch - can u double check db properties you've specified

Comment: We figured it out =)
I had two `context.xml` files that were conflicting with each other since they both had the same xml Resource code. Removing one of them fixed the problem.

Comment: thats gr8! Your code looked fine. It had to be some small issue like this.

Answer (score 1):

**Two possible reasons:**

- `dS.getConnection()` is throwing an exception. Can be **any** exception since your catch block catches everything. You get `NullPointerException` *inside* the catch block because `connection` is `null` at the point of rolling back.
- `dS.getConnection()` is returning a `null` which causes `connection.getAutoCommit()` to throw a `NullPointerException`. This is because `connection` has been set to `null` via `dS.getConnection()`.

In your catch block, start off with an `e.printStackTrace()` to identify the real problem:

```
    ...
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); //This should show you what the real problem is
        try{
            connection.rollback();
        }catch(SQLException ex){
        }
        //throw new EmployeesException(e);
    }finally{
    ...
```

**Solutions:**

- In the catch block, check if `connection` is not `null` before doing rollback. If the database connection was never created, it doesn't have to be rolled back. *I deal with this kind of setup everyday at work in large projects and this is what we do.*
- Less optimal solution: Once `dS.getConnection()` is done, proceed **only** if `connection` is not `null`. You may either use an `if (connection != null) { /* rest of code */ }` or `if (connection == null) throw new NullPointerException();` depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that info in mind and change my code accordingly. Also we figured out that it was two `context.xml` files conflicting. One was in my project folder and the other was in Tomcat's Server project folder. After getting rid of the duplicate(but faulty) line of xml in Tomcat's `context.xml` fixed the issue.

Comment: Good. I have encountered the problem of outdated configuration files too. Anyway it's best to ensure your code is robust with all bases covered properly, even if configuration files are up-to-date and correct. =)